# Angular 4 redirect for my old hash URLs to new without hash URLs is not working

Tags: angular, redirect, angular-routing, angular4-router

we have a single page application which was previously in simple tab structure where all the tab clicks has respective #urls.

Examples: http://tvsntorq.com/#Price, http://tvsntorq.com/#Colour

But now I have implemented this in Angular 4 and now we have urls without hash. Which look like these: http://tvsntorq.com/price, http://tvsntorq.com/colour

Now I have added below routes in my Router Module:

```
...
  {
    path: '#Colour',
    redirectTo: 'colour',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '#Price',
    redirectTo: 'price',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },  
 {
    path: 'colour',
    component: ColorComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'price',
    component: PriceComponent
  }
....
```

But this doesn't seem to work. All I want is to redirect my old with hash url to new without hash corresponding urls. Is it possible? Help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use hash in you URLs you should pass an argument to your `RouterModule.forRoute` in `NgModule`, `imports` section like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoute(yourRoutesArray, {useHash: true})
```

If you don't need it just omit the second argument or send false instead.